# Google map V3 - make markers drop one by one

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Hi~ I have about 200 markers on my map.

I want to make them dropping one by one when the page is loaded, i.e. adding a small delay/interval to each marker's dropping animation.

I tried to archive it by using jQuery's `wait()delay()` and JS's `setTimeout()` methods, but the animation seems to be triggered by the creation of the `Marker` instances, while those methods only working with methods calls. (eg: `setTimeout(function(), 1000);` )So I could get none of them working.

Can anyone please provide a simple solution for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Quick suggestion:
Create your markers but don't set them on a map. Add them to an array. When you're done creating the array, pop the first one and drop it on the map. Set an `animation_changed` event on the marker. When the marker stops dropping it will change it's animation to null. In the event, test what the animation is, and if it null, pop the next marker off and repeat.

Comment: Couldn't find the usage of animation_changed, can you please provide some sample code?

Comment: More exploration on your own will reveal it. Check out information on events: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events and the reference for Markers: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker StackOverflow isn't a place where people write your code for you, or look things up for you.

Comment: hey, i didn't ask you to write any code for me, I was asking for an example, from which i can learn how to write my own code, all right?

Comment: And there are examples in the documentation

Comment: This way is a dead end. If I add the markers into an array and drop them by looping thru it, I won't have the chance to attach the infoBox to them, since each marker's infoBox needs to have different content.